# Download HERE SDK for iOS (PREMIUM EDITION) via Carthage as dependency manager

Tags: here-api

is it possible to use Carthage as a dependency manager to download the HERE SDK FOR IOS (PREMIUM EDITION)? And is yes, how does it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We officially support CocoaPods for our HERE iOS Mobile SDK projects. This is an example of a pod in a routing app project:

```
target 'RoutingApp' do
    platform :ios, '12.0'
    pod 'HEREMaps', '>= 3.14'
end
```

https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/routing-ios/Podfile

I found this article that describes migration steps from Cocoapods:

https://dzone.com/articles/five-steps-to-migrate-an-ios-project-from-cocoapod

Comment: Any plans to support Swift Package Manager?